# Solving a partial differential equation by transformation of variables?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I found an exercise in a book, where one was supposed to transform the differential equation $$y\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-x\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=xyf(x,y)$$ by using the substitutions $x^2+y^2=u$ and $e^{-x^2/2}=v$, and then expressing $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ in terms of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$. By using the chain rule and simplifying things, I get that $$-xyv\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}=-2xyf(x,y).$$ Now the "solutions manual" for this book just divides this with $xy$ on both sides. I do not really know why one can do that. By doing that, we can only say things about the function $f$ off the cordinate axes. Does anyone see anything obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: $x,y=0$ are obviously solutions to your dgl. In the second step we assuming that we are looking for the finite solutions. then we can divide.

Comment: Side note: Refrain from using the old variables in the transformed function $f$ it just confuses the situation for yourself. :)

Comment: @tired, I'm not sure what you mean by "finite" solutions. Anyway, the thing is that then I have to apply a boundary condition, namely $f(0,y)=y^2$. For me to apply this, I have to know what value that $f$ has on the $y$-axis, and I'm not exactly sure how to prove this, since the differential equation only makes me able to prove stuff about the quadrants.

Comment: i mean that for x,y=0 any function f  which is not to singular is a solution to your differential equation.